# Why does Javascript need an anonymous function to delay execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I need to conduct an IP lookup as a prerequisite to proceeding with execution of another function that needs that data. Originally, I called the function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var ipUrl = "myURL?callback=?";    
$.getJSON(ipUrl, function(data) {
        window.ip = data['ip'];
        console.log("inside function" + window.ip);
    }).done(printIp());
});

function printIp() {
    console.log("function is done " + window.ip);   
}
```

However, this outputs as

```
function is done undefined 
inside function <ip_address>
```

I.e. the `printIp()` function is called before the `$.getJSON` is actually complete.

If however, I wrap the `printIp()` call within an anonymous function as follows:

```
$.getJSON(ipUrl, function(data) {
    window.ip = data['ip'];
    console.log("inside function" + window.ip);
}).done(function() {
    printIp();
});
```

I get:

```
inside function <ip_address>
function is done <ip_address>
```

As I would expect. What is going on here? Why do I need to wrap the function call in an anonymous function?

Comment: `()` means _invoke_. You're not passing the _function_ `printIP`, you're passing the result of it's invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code says

```
}).done(printIp());
```

what this does is *calling* `printIp` and using the result of the function call as an argument to the `done` method.

what you actually want is *passing* the function as a `done` handler. use `}).done(printIp);` to do this instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing `printIp` right away. Try it without the `()`:

```
$.getJSON(ipUrl, function(data) {
    window.ip = data['ip'];
    console.log("inside function" + window.ip);
}).done(printIp);
```

Comment: With `()` you are executing a function, without `()` you are actually passing the function as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

pass the function without parantheses, otherwise you are calling it right away:

```
.done(printIp)
```